# To what extent are the firebase rules of Childs overridden by rules set for 'parents' in the database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Say topline in the database you allow authorized users to read but Childs of this database entry you only allow authorized users to read their own entry. Will giving the topline ability for all auth users to read invalidate the child rule where auth users can only read their own?

specifically will people and uid invalidate coordinates?

```
{
  "rules": {
  "people" : {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": true
   ,"$uid": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
     ,  "Education" :{
         ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
      ,"Coordinates" : {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }  
       ,"ForReUpload": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
       ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
      ,"PhotoPosts": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
     ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }

      ,"WhatIamConsideringBuying":  { 
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
      ,"caption": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
      ,"peopleWhoLike" : {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
      ,"peopleWhoLike2" : {
     ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }

      ,"postID" : { 
     ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
      ,"users" : {     
     ".read": "auth.uid != null",
   ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"  
  }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any rule that applies at a high level will affect all children under it.  Children can not remove access granted at a higher level.  I suggest reading the documentation that discuss how [read and write rules cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade):

> Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths. Child rules can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have already declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.
>
> .read and .write rules work from top-down, with shallower rules overriding deeper rules. If a rule grants read or write permissions at a particular path, then it also grants access to all child nodes under it.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to not give the topline database entries any rules and simply address the endpoint child(s)? Those are at  the end of the day the ones that should differ in level or security and the ones that matter. My issue is just coordinates. I don't want them to be readable (ie vulnerable to api attack), but then again I want to use the various users coordinates to calculate distances between then(already didd that). Is it even possible to have the coordinates not be readable to other users and code the app so that distances between users are calculated and used to rank them?

Comment: You can reject access at the top level, then allow it at deeper levels.

Comment: @ Doug Stevenson Thanks. That makes sense. My only worry is even allowing lower read access to the coordinate, wouldn't that still make them vulnerable to api attacks? I'm using CLLocationCoordinate2D in the app to calculate the distance between users.